# React-Native - Module not found: Empty dependency (no request)

Tags: react-native

Im getting this error

```
Module not found: Empty dependency (no request)
C:/Users/tp_re/source/repos/WalkIn/App.js
Module not found: Empty dependency (no request)
```

Code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import DrawerNavigator from './Drawer/DrawerNavigator';

const CustomDrawerComponent = (props)=>(   <SafeAreaView>
<View style={{height:150, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
  <Image source={require('')} style={{height:120, width:120, borderRadius:60}} />
</View>
<ScrollView>
  <DrawerItems {...props} />
</ScrollView>   </SafeAreaView> )
class Login extends Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);

 } 

  loginHandler=()=>{ 
      this.props.navigation.navigate('DrewerNav')
  }
   render(){
      return(
          <View style={styles.container}> 
              <Text> Login </Text>
              <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Button onPress={this.loginHandler}>
                      <Text>Click Me!</Text>
                  </Button>
              </View>

           </View>
       )
   }
}



const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({  
 Login:{
screen:Login
  },

 DrewerNav:{
  screen:DrawerNavigator
  }


},
navigationOptions={
  headerMode:'none'
})

export default function App() {
return (
 <AppStackNavigator />
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```

And:

```
              import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
          import React from 'react';
          import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
          import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


          const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({   
            DrawerScreen1: {
              screen: DrawerScreen1,
              navigationOptions: {
                drawerLabel: 'DrawerScreen1',
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="user-circle" size={17} />,
              }   },

            DrawerScreen2: {
              screen: DrawerScreen2,
              navigationOptions: {
                drawerLabel: 'DrawerScreen2',
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="user-circle" size={17} />,
              }   },

            DrawerScreen3: {
              screen: DrawerScreen3,
              navigationOptions: {
                drawerLabel: 'DrawerScreen3',
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="user-circle" size={17} />,
              }   }, }, {   drawerPosition :"right",   contentComponent:CustomDrawerComponent

          });

          export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: You did not export ```CustomDrawerComponent``` in your first file, and did not import it in second file.